# Elastic Search on XML File Contents

Tags: rest, elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search . My usecase is to search a text inside some set of XML Files.  So my question is .

1. Is this attainable using Elastic Search
2. I tried the following  :

   Installed the Elastic search , applied the attachment plugin

Created a Mapping:

```
  curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/second/?pretty=1'  -d '
 {
        "mapping" : {
            "xmlfile" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "attachment": { "type" : "attachment" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Indexed an XML File:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/second/xmlfile?pretty=1" -d '
       {
      "file" : "'`base64 D:\\games.xml | perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/g'`'"
       }
```

Tried searching :

```
 curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/second/xmlfile/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "text" : {
         "file" : "curField"  //currField is a string inside my xml
      }
   }
}
```

The above search gave me SearchNotFound Exception  so i d

```
 curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/second/xmlfile/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "term" : {
         "file" : "curField"  //currField is a string inside my xml
      }
   }
}
```

Which gave me :

```
{
   "took": 14,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 0,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": []
   }
}
```

its saying 0 hits.
I also tried converting my xml to JSON Object and indexing. But this is a lot of work for my program . Can somebody help me with this ? Why is it saying 0 hits when the XML contains the string ?

Answer (score 5):

> 1 . XML search - Is this attainable using Elastic Search

Yes absolutely.
However I'd take a different approach to the one you have. 
I would instead

1. Create a custom analyser to parse the XML data. For example if you're not interested in the tags and instead only data within the tags, use the [html strip char filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html).
2. Store the XML document in a single string field - [attachment](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-attachment-type.html) is mostly for binary data and I'm guessing that your XML document is ASCII or UTF-8.